# Use Take() to get a limited number of results but also get the potential total

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

Given the following...

```
int maxResults = 25;
string code = "Thailand";

var q = from i in images where i.component_code == code select i;

var images = q.OrderByDescending(x => x.image_rating).Take(maxResults);

if (images.Count() > 0)
{
    ...

    lblResult = string.Format("Viewing {0} Images Of A Possible {1}", images.Count(), ?);
}
```

How do I get the potential total number of images that would have been returned if Take() had not been used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you use q.Count() for this?

Comment: performace wise, at what point does linq hit the database and does it hit the database twice, once to get the count and second to get the subset of results?

Comment: You will have two queries to the database, but if you weren't using LINQ (LINQ to SQL I guess) how would do this? You need two queries.